Book about an orphan girl who found out she's from a different world/realm and can't tell her mortal boyfriend/friend
All I can remember is that there was a an orphan girl who found out she's from a different world/realm. She can't tell her mortal boyfriend/friend.

In roughly which year did you read this? And can you tell us anything more at all about the plot, characters, setting, etc? There are probably dozens if not hundreds of books that match your current description.
